# Reuse java connectionpool in scala

Tags: java, scala, bonecp, scalikejdbc

I have a legacy Java application, and would like to reuse its database connection handling when extending the app with scala.

The existing application does this to use the database (with try/catch omitted):

```
Connection dbConn = NewConnectionPool.getRemotePool().getConnection();
PreparedStatement ps = dbConn.prepareStatement(someQuery);
```

in the scala code I tried:

```
  class Rules {
  val connHandle = NewConnectionPool.getRemotePool.getConnection
  val session = connHandle.unwrap(classOf[java.sql.Connection])
  def loadTagRulesFromDb(name: String = "rules"): tagRuleSet = {
        //val tagRules = NamedDB('remotedb) readOnly { implicit session =>
        val tagRules = DB readOnly { implicit session =>
          sql"select * from databasename.messaging_routing_matchers".map(
            rs => tagRule(
              rs.long("id"),
              rs.string("description"),
              rs.long("ruleid"),
              rs.string("operator"),
              rs.string("target")
            )
          ).list.apply
        }
        for (tr <- tagRules) {
          println(tr)
        }
        tagRuleSet(name,DateTime.now(),tagRules)
      }
    }
```

and call it like:

```
Rules rr = new Rules();
rr.loadTagRulesFromDb("testing");
```

and I get this error (both with DB and the NamedDB version) "`Connection pool is not yet initialized.(name:'`" with name either default or remotedb):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection pool is not yet initialized.(name:'default)
    at scalikejdbc.ConnectionPool$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ConnectionPool.scala:76) ~[scalikejdbc-core_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at scalikejdbc.ConnectionPool$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ConnectionPool.scala:74) ~[scalikejdbc-core_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121) ~[scala-library-2.11.8.jar:na]
    at scalikejdbc.ConnectionPool$.get(ConnectionPool.scala:74) ~[scalikejdbc-core_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at scalikejdbc.ConnectionPool$.apply(ConnectionPool.scala:65) ~[scalikejdbc-core_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at scalikejdbc.DB$.connectionPool(DB.scala:151) ~[scalikejdbc-core_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at scalikejdbc.DB$.readOnly(DB.scala:172) ~[scalikejdbc-core_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at dk.coolsms.smsc.Rules.loadTagRulesFromDb(Rules.scala:28) ~[smsc.jar:na]
    at dk.coolsms.smsc.SendMessage.sendMessage(SendMessage.java:206) ~[smsc.jar:na]
```

I assume that I can get a scalikejdbc compatible connection from the BoneCP connectionHandle somehow?

EDIT: the solution is below, note that `DB readOnly etc.` should not be used since it relies on `DBs.setupAll()` and application.conf, which does not apply in this specific case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing via a `javax.sql.DataSource` instance would be the best way to integrate ScalikeJDBC with existing database connections.

http://scalikejdbc.org/documentation/connection-pool.html

But you already have a raw `java.sql.Connection`, it's also possible to simply create a `DBSession` as below:

```
implicit val session = DBSession(conn)
sql"select * from databasename.messaging_routing_matchers".toMap.list.apply()
```